# Add rows whose columns are number in R or refer a column whose name is a number

Tags: r, identity-column

This question maybe is silly.  How can I add the rows in the following dataframe whose columns are numbers. Can We do it without change the column names.  Thanks.

```
Perinatal_Region     1     2   NaN total
           1     13456 12770   1     
           2     36975 35470  NA     
           3    19116 18156   2     
           4    84653 81120   4     
           5    57015 54313   4     
           NaN     1     1   NA
```

Comment: Do you want to eliminate the rows with NAs?

Comment: No. I like to have the total of all rows.  Question is that we can identify the columns whose names are numbers? The dataframe is obtained by transformation.

Comment: If you just want to sum a row of data.frame in R you can use `sum(data.frame[row.number,],na.rm=TRUE)`. This will "ignore" the NAs present in your data. Say your data.frame is called test, and you want to sum the 10th row: `sum(test[10,],na.rm=TRUE)`. Does that help?

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do. What is your desired output? For summing the rows just do `rowSums(df, na.rm = T)`

Comment: `df$Total <- rowSums(df[,grep("\\d+", colnames(df))])`

Comment: I tried to use syntax like this: pop1 <- within(pop, total = sum(column2 + column3 + column4)). Since column name is number, so I was not bale to get results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of ways:

```
df <- structure(list(Perinatal_Region = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NaN), `1` = c(13456L, 
36975L, 19116L, 84653L, 57015L, 1L), `2` = c(12770L, 35470L, 
18156L, 81120L, 54313L, 1L), `NaN` = c(1L, NA, 2L, 4L, 4L, NA
)), .Names = c("Perinatal_Region", "1", "2", "NaN"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

 rowSums(df[,grep("\\d+", colnames(df))])
 #[1]  26226  72445  37272 165773 111328      2
```

If it is:

```
  colSums(df[,grep("\\d+", colnames(df))])
  #    1      2 
 #211216 201830
```

Or

```
 within(df, Total<- `1` +`2`)
 #  Perinatal_Region     1     2 NaN  Total
 #1                1 13456 12770   1  26226
 #2                2 36975 35470  NA  72445
 #3                3 19116 18156   2  37272
 #4                4 84653 81120   4 165773
 #5                5 57015 54313   4 111328
 #6              NaN     1     1  NA      2

 addmargins(as.table(as.matrix(df[,c("1", "2")])))
 #         1      2    Sum
 #A    13456  12770  26226
 #B    36975  35470  72445
 #C    19116  18156  37272
 #D    84653  81120 165773
 #E    57015  54313 111328
 #F        1      1      2
 #Sum 211216 201830 413046
```

To all the columns `1`, `2` and `NaN`

```
 within(df, Total<- `1` +`2` +`NaN`) 

 rowSums(df[,grep("\\d+|NaN", colnames(df))], na.rm=T)
 #[1]  26227  72445  37274 165777 111332      2
```

Comment: Thanks. How can we do it if we like to add all three cols:1,2,NaN?

Comment: Thank you. rowSums works but the within does not work for NA row.

Comment: @user1582755.  It works for me.  You could show the example using `dput(head(data, 6))`

Comment: I do not know why. I copied all your codes. The total for the row having NA is NA.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum only the columns named with a number:

```
data <- data.frame(Perinatal_region = c(1,2,3,4,5,1/0), one = c(13456,36975,19116,84653,57015,1 ), two = c(12770, 35470, 18156, 81120, 54313, 1)) 
names(data) <- c("Perinatal_region", "1", "2")
columns_to_sum <- c()

for(name in names(data)){
  if (is.na(as.numeric(name))==FALSE){ #If the name is not a number as.numeric() returns NA
     columns_to_sum <- c(columns_to_sum, name)
   }

}

a <- colSums(data[columns_to_sum])
```

This is the result:

```
> a
     1      2 
211216 201830
```